# Must specify either a render prop, a render function as children, or a component prop to Field(auto)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form, final-form

I am getting error this while developing `Auto complete` using `final-form`

**Must specify either a render prop, a render function as children, or a component prop to Field(auto)**

I take help from this link
https://trejgun.github.io/articles/bindings-for-using-final-form-with-material-ui-autocomplete/

But when I implemented above code I am getting above error

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-breeze-hv58o

```
 <Field
              name="auto"
              multiple={true}
              component={AutoCompleteWrapper}
              placeholder="First Name"
              options={[{ label: "The Shawshank Redemption", values: 1994 }]}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codesandbox, in test.js, you are exporting `AutoCompleteWrapper` as a *named* export:

```
export const AutoCompleteWrapper = props => {
```

But in your index.js file, you are importing it as the *default*:

```
import AutoCompleteWrapper from "./test";
```

So you can fix that in one of two ways:

**Import the named export**

```
import { AutoCompleteWrapper } from "./test";
```

**Change your export to be the default**

```
const AutoCompleteWrapper = props => {
  ...
};

export default AutoCompleteWrapper;
```